# Leaflet filter markers by name using checkbox

Tags: javascript, filter, leaflet, markers

I want to filter my markers by name, using `map.addLayer(nameOfTheMarker)` and `map.remvoeLayer(nameOfTheLayer)` with a checkbox like this:

```
$('#markertoggle').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
         map.addLayer(nameOfTheMarker);
    else 
        map.remvoeLayer(nameOfTheLayer;
});
```

I found a jsfiddle with an example of a filter, but I don't know how to apply it to my code:

```
var locations = [
['AB11 5HW','17','A',57.147701,-2.085442 ] ,
['AB11 8DG','3','B',57.129372,-2.090916 ]
];

var markersA = [];
var markersB = [];

//Loop through the initial array and add to two different arrays based on the specified variable
for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    switch (locations[i][2]) {            
        case 'A' : 
            markersA.push(L.marker([locations[i][3], locations[i][4]]));
            break;        
        case 'B' :
            markersB.push(L.marker([locations[i][3], locations[i][4]]));
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}

//add the groups of markers to layerGroups
var groupA = L.layerGroup(markersA);
var groupB = L.layerGroup(markersB);

//background tile set
var tileLayer = {'Gray' : L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
};

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(57.0, -2),
    zoom: 9,
    layers: [tileLayer['Gray'], groupA, groupB] //change this to determine which ones start loaded on screen
});


//Control on the Top Left that handles the switching between A and B
var overlayMaps = {
    "A": groupA,
    "B": groupB
};
L.control.layers(tileLayer, overlayMaps, {position:'topleft'}).addTo(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RogerHN/31v2afte/2/

The function that I use to pull the markers:

```
function showMarkersByName(name) {
for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
    var resName = markers.resources[i].name;

    if (resName == name) {
        var resIcon = icons.resources[i].icon;
        var resSize = icons.resources[i].size;
        var resPname = icons.resources[i].pname;

        var customIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: resIcon,
            iconSize: resSize, // size of the icon
            iconAnchor:   [resSize[0]/2, resSize[1]/2], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor:  [2, -resSize[1]/2] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });

        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
            var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
            var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

            marker = L.marker([y, x], {icon: customIcon});
            marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);
            $(marker._icon).addClass(name)

        }
    }
}
```

My markers structure its very similar with the one in the example, I just don't know where in my function I need to insert the filter to filter the markers by name, adding then to a layer to later toggle them use the checkbox above.

My full code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UwAelIuUYz4OkoOG7zFn?p=preview

Comment: Really confused right now. Yesterday i gave you a complete working example with layer toggling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416447/how-to-add-a-marker-with-a-specific-class-to-a-layer-or-layergroup What's wrong with that?

Comment: Hey iH8, I tried that example, but got no luck, (I am new to javascript, most of the code that I have I learned from examples and help over here). I had trouble to implement you example on my code, I want to toggle the layers using a checkbox, and not a control (Don't know how to toggle Layergroups using a checkbox). Your example is a good one, the problem is that I am not very skilled to implement it.

Comment: Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, still confused. The fiddle you are linking to also uses the `L.Control.Layers` control? And now you're saying you don't want to use a control?

Comment: Finally! Using your first code and a bit of the one I mentioned above I was able to achieve what I wanted. I didn't wanted to use L.Control.layers because I don't like the appearence of it. Instead I wanted a checkbox to add and remove the layers with the markers.

Comment: Ok nice, perhaps throw in an answer and edit this question to say it's solved so that others won't go through the effort of trying to help you when you've already helped yourself :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103948/discussion-between-rogerhn-and-ih8).

Comment: I posted the answer and all the code that I used. See what I mean with the checkbox instead of a control? The checkbox I can style to match the theme of the page. I will apply this code to a map with 5950 markers. Which now are loaded into html once the page loads, and after this, will be more fast because the markers code will only load if the user toggle it.

Comment: I cannot accept my answer today... That's why I marked it with [solved] temporary; tomorrow I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example above and the code iH8 mentioned I was able to create a checkbox to toggle markers filtering them by its name:

```
function initLayerGroups() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
    switch (markers.resources[i].name) {
      case 'GreenMarker':
        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
          var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
          var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

          marker = L.marker([y, x], {
            icon: getIcon(i)
          }).bindPopup(getPopupContent(i));

          markersGreen.push(marker);
        }
        break;
      case 'BlueMarker':
        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
          var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
          var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

          marker = L.marker([y, x], {
            icon: getIcon(i)
          }).bindPopup(getPopupContent(i));

          markersBlue.push(marker);
        }
        break;
      case 'RedMarker':
        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
          var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
          var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

          marker = L.marker([y, x], {
            icon: getIcon(i)
          }).bindPopup(getPopupContent(i));

          markersRed.push(marker);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  groupGreen = L.layerGroup(markersGreen);
  groupBlue = L.layerGroup(markersBlue);
  groupRed = L.layerGroup(markersRed);
}
```

The checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="greenmarkertoggle"/>
<label for="greenmarkertoggle">Green Marker</label>
```

And the javascript code to show or hide the layer:

```
$('#greenmarkertoggle').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      map.addLayer(groupGreen);
    else
      map.removeLayer(groupGreen);
});
```

And here's the full working example using the code above:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GuIVhtFdtMDbmZdME1bV?p=preview

Thanks to iH8 and the example above I was able to create that function and filter the markers by its name.